# Simple loop for rolling dices n times

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, android-studio

Let's summarize the problem:

I want to create a simple dice game with two players, each player can roll the dice only five times. After the five tries, the turn goes to the other player.

Excuse me, I'm a beginner, this question may seem simple or stupid but any help would be appreciated.

So, how can I run `rollDice` 5 times.

I tried a for loop or do while, but seems that I'm too nab to do this, that's why I'm asking for help.

Rules of the game : http://0x0.st/isnA.txt

```
public void rollDice(View view) {
    MediaPlayer diceSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dicesound);
    diceSound.start();
    vibrator.vibrate(100);
    diceStatus.setText("Rolling..");
    Random ranNumber = new Random();
    rotationdice();
    int numOfRolls = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRolls; i++) {
        dice1Number = ranNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dice2Number = ranNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dice3Number = ranNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dice4Number = ranNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dice5Number = ranNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;


        switch (dice1Number) {
            case 1:
                dice1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice1);
                break;
            case 2:
                dice1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice2);
                break;
            case 3:
                dice1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice3);
                break;
            case 4:
                dice1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice4);
                break;
            case 5:
                dice1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice5);
                break;
            case 6:
                dice1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice6);
                break;
        }
        switch (dice2Number) {
            case 1:
                dice2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice1);
                break;
            case 2:
                dice2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice2);
                break;
            case 3:
                dice2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice3);
                break;
            case 4:
                dice2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice4);
                break;
            case 5:
                dice2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice5);
                break;
            case 6:
                dice2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice6);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (dice3Number) {
            case 1:
                dice3View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice1);
                break;
            case 2:
                dice3View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice2);
                break;
            case 3:
                dice3View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice3);
                break;
            case 4:
                dice3View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice4);
                break;
            case 5:
                dice3View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice5);
                break;
            case 6:
                dice3View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice6);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (dice4Number) {
            case 1:
                dice3View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice1);
                break;
            case 2:
                dice3View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice2);
                break;
            case 3:
                dice4View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice3);
                break;
            case 4:
                dice4View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice4);
                break;
            case 5:
                dice4View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice5);
                break;
            case 6:
                dice4View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice6);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (dice5Number) {
            case 1:
                dice5View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice1);
                break;
            case 2:
                dice5View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice2);
                break;
            case 3:
                dice5View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice3);
                break;
            case 4:
                dice5View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice4);
                break;
            case 5:
                dice5View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice5);
                break;
            case 6:
                dice5View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice6);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        showDiceNumber();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `dice1Number` ???

Comment: why do the player wants to roll the dice 5 times.

Comment: dice1Number is an int

Why a player rolls 5 times, i update the post with rules

Comment: Please show your attempt.  Posting the entire function is not material to your question.  You already wrote a `for` loop to do something a given number of times -- all you need to do is apply that principle to calling your function.  Show us how that failed, and we can fix it.  Otherwise, the standard advice is to return to your tutorial on `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

Java's an object oriented language.  Start thinking in terms of objects:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008610/simple-loop-for-rolling-dices-n-times
 */
public class Die {

    public static final int DEFAULT_NUM_SIDES = 6;

    private Random random;
    private int numSides;

    public Die() {
        this(null, DEFAULT_NUM_SIDES);
    }

    public Die(int numSides) {
        this(null, numSides);
    }

    public Die(Long seed) {
        this(seed, DEFAULT_NUM_SIDES);
    }

    public Die(Long seed, int numSides) {
        if (numSides <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of sides must be greater than zero");
        this.random = (seed != null) ? new Random(seed) : new Random();
        this.numSides = numSides;
    }

    public int roll() {
        return this.random.nextInt(this.numSides)+1;
    }
}
```

Here's a JUnit test:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008610/simple-loop-for-rolling-dices-n-times
 */
public class DieTest {

    @Test
    public void testRoll_Success() {
        // setup
        Die die = new Die(1957L);
        List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5);
        Map<Integer, Long> expectedFrequency = new TreeMap<Integer, Long>() {{
            put(1, 5L);
            put(2, 3L);
            put(3, 6L);
            put(4, 3L);
            put(5, 2L);
            put(6, 1L);
        }};
        // exercise
        List<Integer> actual = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < expected.size(); ++i) {
            actual.add(die.roll());
        }
        Map<Integer, Long> actualFrequency = actual.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedFrequency, actualFrequency);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think having an integer variable `DEFAULT_NUM_SIDES` and also passing the number of sides as a variable are both completely redundant elements. It doesn't seem this case will ever consider special, irregular-shaped dice and we all know that a normal dice has 6 sides. Therefore, you could get rid of the two first constructors for `Die`. I'm only suggesting this edit, to make the code simpler to understand, as the OP is obviously a beginner. If we consider dice with arbitrary numbers of sides, then this is a very good answer

Comment: I did it for completeness and education. It would make a nice two sided coin. I think you are being too literal, without benefit. The OP might be a beginner, but this isn’t hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

think of your problem in small steps:

first, a user can roll the dice up to 5 times until the next user gets a turn at their 5 rolls.
your function rolldice already does 5 rolls for one person.
so just pass rolldice from one person to the other person.

example :

```
 person1.dice = rollDice();
person2.dice = rollDice();
```

unfortunately the question isnt precise enough to give you some precise help , but i hope i put you on the right path.

change the functions signature to return the dice roll result insteadof returning void.

if you really really want to do your forloop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
   rollDice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you catch yourself **repeating code**, then you're doing something wrong. Object-Oriented languages focus a lot on re-usability and knowing how to do this, is very beneficial to a programmer. So, the following should be a method and not repeated 5 times for each throw. You can **call** that method with each throw. See below:

   ```
   public void doDiceRoll(Random rand){ // need to pass the RNG as parameter
       switch (rand.nextInt(6) + 1) { //switch statement for a random number 1-6
           case 1:
               dice.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice1);
               break;
           case 2:
               dice.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice2);
               break;
           case 3:
               dice.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice3);
               break;
           case 4:
               dice.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice4);
               break;
           case 5:
               dice.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice5);
               break;
           case 6:
               dice.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice6);
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

---

2. Because your question is not very clear as to what your problem is, I can only assume that you *forgot to store the results from the dice rolls* and every time there is a dice roll, it just gets discarded. So, there are two possibilities of doing what you want to achieve.

   - You either want to stop after each roll, showing the result only on the screen.
   - You either want to perform the 5 rolls automatically (just like your for-loop does). But if you want the rolls to be automatic, then you need to store the results.
   - Or finally, you might want to stop after each roll AND store the results as well.

So what are you missing? That's right, a data structure (e.g. integer array) to hold all your results.

In the code below, you can clearly see an integer array called `results`. With each loop you add the 'result' into that array.

```
public void rollDice(View view) {
        final int numOfRolls = 5;
        MediaPlayer diceSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dicesound);
        diceSound.start();
        vibrator.vibrate(100);
        diceStatus.setText("Rolling..");
        rotationdice(); //I DON'T KNOW WHAT THIS DOES.
        int[] results = new int[5];
        Random ranNumber = new Random();

        //THIS FOR-LOOP WILL BE EXECUTED 5 TIMES. BUT IT WILL DO THIS VERY FAST.
        //YOU HAVE TO THINK OF A WAY TO STOP EITHER BEFORE A ROLL (LOOP STRUCTURED IN A DIFFERENT WAY)
        //OR YOU MIGHT WANT THE 5 ROLLS TO BE COMPLETED AUTOMATICALLY LIKE SO. SO THERE NEEDS TO BE
        //A PAUSE BETWEEN PLAYS.
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRolls; i++) {
            dice = doDiceRoll(ranNumber);
            results[i] = /* ADD SOME WAY TO GET THE DICE NUMBER AND STORE IT IN THE ARRAY*/;
            showDiceNumber();
        }
    }
```

So, to **conclude**. I have showed you how to **not** repeat code and gave you some 'food for thought' (should the program get user input after every dice roll? should the program do all 5 rolls automatically like you're currently doing? etc..). Think about what you want your program to be like, what you want it to do and break down the process into different steps. It's good practice to be as specific as possible to understand the flow of your program. Pen and Paper always help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a variable to store the number of times the dice has been rolled.

```
int amount = 0
```

Should be the default value. I don't know much of Java myself but you have to put in the `RollDice()` function to add 1 to the variable `amount` and an `if` statement to switch users when `amount` becomes `5`.